# Is there a jQuery wrapper for .Net?

Tags: .net, jquery, wrapper

I've noticed that there are wrappers for a lot of javascript libraries and such, but I have yet to see anything significant for jQuery.

Am I just not searching hard enough and there is one out there? Or is there some problem with jQuery that keeps someone from creating a wrapper?

Comment: Does this count? http://www.hanselman.com/blog/jQueryToShipWithASPNETMVCAndVisualStudio.aspx

Comment: That is true, and very awesome, but it doesn't seem like microsoft will be making it so you can use jQuery without diving into javascript.

Comment: Why do you need a wrapper? It will just make the markup more complex and add overhead when really not necessary...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your signals may be a bit crossed here regarding the proper use of JQuery and ASP.NET.

JQuery *is* a wrapper that simplifies Javascript (in particular, access to page elements). It is a client side technology.

ASP.NET is mostly a server-side technology.  While you can place controls on the page that will emit javascript (e.g. control validation) and there are a variety of ways in which Javascript is employed to simplify WebForms development, ASP.NET it isn't really about client-side programming in the same way that JQuery is.

Honestly, I *wouldn't want* ASP.NET to wrap JQuery as it would just lead to impedence mismatches between how you handle client and server-side processing.  Plus, JQuery really is pretty easy.

Comment: Yes, jQuery is very easy. I've made a few server side controls myself that used it. It just seems like I'm to the point that I'm reinventing the wheel because I think surely someone else has made this same control using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I found that one: http://jquerycs.codeplex.com/

However I still agree with Mark, it's not really neccesary (but I can see the value with asp.net webforms to avoid ClientIDs soup).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.dotnetgurus.net/post/2014/05/28/asp-net-wrapper-control-for-jquery-ui-slider

Not a library including a full set of wrapper controls for all jQuery UI widgets. But gives a really good example of how to write a wrapper control in Asp.Net for jquery UI widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a jQuery wrapper for the ASP.NET AJAX library, or an ASP.NET AJAX library that wraps jQuery?

There are some server-side ASP.NET controls available that wrap some jQuery effects. http://clipperhouse.com/jQuery/

Also, check out CodePlex as there are TONS of projects hosted there for server-side jQuery wrappers and client-side extenders.

http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?projectSearchText=jquery

Comment: An ASP.NET library that wraps jQuery with controls and/or extenders.

Comment: Check out CodePlex for several libraries that offer jQuery server controls.

Answer (score 0):

http://juiceui.com/

Juice UI is an open-source collection of WebForms components that brings jQuery UI Widgets to your project with ease.